# Не выдаёт шляпу Silencium?

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Из [описания](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/silencium):

> Silencium
>
> опубликуйте ответ на вопрос без комментариев; ваш ответ останется без
>   комментариев с рейтингом +7

Вот [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759297/213987), все требования выполнены:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так?

Comment: Может нужен хотя бы один комментарий с 7 апами?

Comment: Или +7 означает больше семи, сча проверю..

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Ничего не поменялось. Возможно, на вопросе были комментарии раньше, которые потом были удалены? Есть кто-то с привилегией 'читать анекдоты'?

Comment: @AK есть, но анекдоты в комментариях мы читать не можем. Вам модераторы нужны.

Comment: Боже, мои глаза... Как вы читаете такой мелкий шрифт? Строчные буквы всего пять пикселей в высоту.

Comment: @Arhad Не пугайтесь, у меня стоит дефолтный шрифт в FF на Crtl + 0, просто я когда делал скриншот решил что по ширине не вместится скрин, поэтому пару раз зум крутанул на мышке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> answer a question that has never been commented on; your answer gets no comments and scores 7+

> ответьте на вопрос, который никогда не комментировали; ваш ответ должен остаться без комментариев, но набрать 7+ баллов

Источник: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304341/309650

Дело в том, что у вопроса были комментарии:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Да, тогда не баг, не кеш и не магия. Спасибо.

Comment: @AK вот и играй по этим играм, когда не имеешь исходных данных. Надо писать жалобу, я считаю.

Comment: @AK, обновил ответ.

Comment: @alexolut писать жалобу на что?

Comment: @Kromster на реализацию. Во время ответа создаётся ошибочная видимость выполнения условий. Такого быть не должно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а посмотреть, были комментарии или нет, может только модератор?

Comment: @HamSter, да, просматривать удалённые комментарии может только модератор. В таймлайне тоже показываются только модераторам. Других способов проверить не знаю.

Comment: @HamSter, про принятость ответа в этом описании ничего не говорится.

Comment: @HamSter, где комментарии искать?

Comment: @HamSter, ну так там у вопроса 3 комментария.